# how to access folders in you project inc#?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

i need to access folder in project .I have used Directory.CurrentDirectory and it is not working is there a way to access folders in Folder structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

r u trying to access with in the project folder meanz local folder???
if u trying that so u can use this one in my case m creating folder u can change it

StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Folder Name", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

and also u can access folder with given uri path like this, in my case m pick images from local folder within the project..

private String imagePath = null;
ImageSource image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/Folder Name/"), this.imagePath));